# Laraver eloquent lists method in tests

Tags: php, testing, laravel, eloquent

The target is to convert eloquent result list to `<select>` tag.

I am doing like this:

Class `TransactionPurposeRepository`

```
protected $_transactionPurpose;


function __construct(TransactionPurpose $transactionPurpose)
{
    $this->_transactionPurpose = $transactionPurpose;
}


/**
 * Get all the transaction purposes
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function all()
{
    return $this->_transactionPurpose->all();
}
```

In controller i have:

```
$purposes = $this->_transactionPurposeRepo->all();
print_r($purposes->lists('id')); die();
```

In browser (ok):

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )
```

In console (testing):

```
PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/yuriikrevnyi/sites/zp.dev/www/phpunit.xml

.......................................PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function lists() on a non-object in /Users/yuriikrevnyi/sites/zp.dev/www/app/zp/controllers/TransactionsController.php on line 79

Fatal error: Call to a member function lists() on a non-object in /Users/yuriikrevnyi/sites/zp.dev/www/app/zp/controllers/TransactionsController.php on line 79
```

Key line is here `Call to a member function lists() on a non-object`.

**The question is: what the hell is going on?**

Comment: I guess our question for you is... what does `TransactionPurpose->all()` return? Are you making expectations on the call to `->all()` in your test without specifying a return value that can receive `->lists()`?

Comment: TransactionPurpose is a simple Eloquent model

Comment: And are you mocking it in your tests and then setting an expectation on the `all` method? If so, are you specifying that it should return an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` or at least some mocked object that expects `lists`?

Comment: it has finally worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have modified tests to be like:

```
$purposes = new Collection([new TransactionPurpose, new TransactionPurpose]);

$this->_repo
    ->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn(Mockery::mock([
        'all' => $purposes,
        'lists' => $purposes->toArray()
    ]));
```